# I can't delete item from NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, arrays, xcode, nsmutablearray

I can't solve the problem. There is an array `NSMutableArray *array`, which contains the following values ​​`(@ "1", @ "2", @ "3", @ "4", @ "5")`.

I remove the first element and should get an array with the following values ​​`(@ "2", @ "3", @ "4", @ "5")`, where the value of `@"2"` has `index = 0`.

```
 [array removeObjectAtIndex:0];
     NSLog(@"Arr after removal is  : %@",array);
```

and in the console I get:

```
2
3
4
5
```

But! When I put a break point then in debug area I see the following:

```
->[0]=(id)0x00000000
->[1]=(id)0x092701a0 (int)2
->[2]=(id)0x092701b0 (int)3
->[3]=(id)0x092701c0 (int)4
```

I don't understand what's happen with element which has a value "5" and why the first element was not removed, but only equated nil??? If anyone encountered this problem - tell me please
Thanks.

Comment: I have test same and show properly, which version of Xcode n ios you are using?

Comment: and if you array is `(@ "1", @ "2", @ "3", @ "4", @ "5")` this type of value that it is array of **String not an int**.

Comment: Wait so the console is printing out the correct values but your issue is the empty memory address of all 0's ???? you understand thats equal to nil right ?

Comment: Ok.. First i have tested in xcode5 , and its show correct, when i check it in xcode 4.6 it show what you said..

Comment: Don't trust the debugger "Variables" view, it is sometimes plain wrong. Use NSLog, or `po` in the debugger console. That should show the correct value.

Comment: Your Question title is wrong, it is deleting from array.

Comment: use NSLog and it will correctly show remaining values.

Answer (score 0):

The implementation of NSArray and related classes doesn't necessarily using a traditional C array behind the scenes. What you see when inspecting an object in the debugger object browser isn't the thing you should rely on. See [this excellent article](http://ridiculousfish.com/blog/posts/array.html) for more details.

If you remove the item from the array, and the array object acts like the first item has been removed, then its job is done. *How* it does it isn't your problem.